# Most simple FrameworkElement to handle HorizontalAlignment and VerticalAlignment?

Tags: c#, silverlight, popup, alignment, frameworkelement

This is Silverlight.

Initial goal is to display a random element in a Popup with some VerticalAlignment and HorizontalAlignment. I do not want to use VerticalOffset or HorizontalOffset, because there is more to what I really want to do, including some complex bindings.

First attempt was:

```
<Popup>
    <Button
        Height="135"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
</Popup>
```

Second attempt was:

```
<Popup
    Height="135"
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
    VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
    <Button />
</Popup>
```

Both were a failure: the Button was always on Top and not Stretch (HorizontalAlignment and VerticalAlignment didn't work).

So I had the idea to encapsulate the element in a simple FrameworkElement:

```
<Popup>
    <Border>
        <Button
            Height="135"
            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
            VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
    </Border>
</Popup>
```

And it is working.

But I had to use `Border` in this example, when I could have done it with `Grid` and many other `FrameworkElement` (but not with Canvas or Viewbox or Popup). I'd like to know what is the most simple, efficient and processor-friendly transparent FrameworkElement to encapsulate another element with working HorizontalAlignment and VerticalAlignment? Is it:

- Border? (like the above example)
- UserControl?
- ContentControl?
- ContentContainer?
- some custom and basic MyFrameworkElement? (might need help for most basic implementation)
- something else like Grid?

Comment: Whenever I need a "wrapper element" I use the `Border`. By default the BorderThickness is 0 and no Background is set.

Comment: @Martin Currently I hesitate between Border, UserControl, ContentControl and ContentContainer. I'm giving a try to ContentContainer as it got less properties than others.

Answer (score 1):

WPF controls come in two flavors:  Ones that interact with users (like accept user clicks like a button, or display text like a text block) and containers that control placement and layout of the previous ones.

Container controls are usually designed to lay out their children in a specific manner.  For example, Canvases lay out children by X, Y, Width & Height values.  Each one has a specific use, so you must [read the documentation or tutorials for these container controls](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140613/WPF-Tutorial-Layout-Panels-Containers-Layout-Trans) and understand how each works in order to select the appropriate one for a task.

In your case, you want the button to fill all available space in the popup (it seems, it isn't that clear).  I know that the Grid does this by default.  So I would do the following:

```
<Popup><Grid><Button /></Grid></Popup>
```

Comment: No, not filling the whole space, just having it's HorizontalAlignment and VerticalAlignment properties working. It works with *Border*, *ContentControl*, *UserControl* and *Grid*. I want to know which one of those is the most basic and processor-friendly.

Comment: @Cœur "most basic" and "processor-friendly" are pointless at this level.  But ContentControl does not control the positioning of its child controls, as it is the base class of all containers.  Use that one.  It won't make any appreciable difference on memory or performance, however.